# MVC2 - passing C# code in javascript function on page

Tags: javascript, function, asp.net-mvc-2, escaping

I have a input button and onclick I want to fire a javascript function and pass my C# object property. It contains an ID which I will need with an Ajax function. I am having an issue with correctly escaping my quotes.

```
 <td><input type="button" value='Contact query' onclick="sendQuery"'(<%=Model.AssociatedLists[0].Id.ToString()%>)'"/></td>

 function sendQuery(param) {
        alert(param);
    }
```

This is how the html is formed in my browser:

```
<input onclick="sendQuery" type="button" '(e543cd31-7491-432e-b8a4-9718ad2c44e2)"="" value="Contact query"/>
```

My button doesn't fire because my HTML isn't well formed.

Any help please?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Instead of

```
<input type="button" value='Contact query' onclick="sendQuery"'(<%=Model.AssociatedLists[0].Id.ToString()%>)'"/>
```

Use

```
<input type="button" value='Contact query' onclick="sendQuery('<%=Model.AssociatedLists[0].Id.ToString()%>')"/>
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. I got confused because visual studio is giving me red swiggly where there is (' and ')". But in the browser it works.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but besides adding context to my answer... have you added anything else? It seems just a copy to me and to make things worse it was accepted as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
onclick="sendQuery('<%=Model.AssociatedLists[0].Id.ToString()%>')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `onclick` reference, add an id on the button and try the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#your-button-id').click(function () {
            sendQuery(<%=Model.AssociatedLists[0].Id.ToString() %>);
        });
    });
</script>
```